# Data is not showing in page using Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I am new to Ionic and trying to develop a Food Ordering Application using Ionic 4 and Woocommerce API.

I am able to fetch record from API. When I click on Side Menu Item Category name, it is retrieving items under that category id.

Inside the item listing page, items are showing only when I am resizing the chrome browser using inspect element from desktop to mobile view or vice versa or any kind of refresh is happening. We may assume that the information is in hidden state and on resizing or refreshing it is visible to user.

The same thing happening when ion-infinite-scroll option I am using.

Any idea how to load the data when the new page will load as well as scrolling the page?? Please let me know if you need any further information for the same.

Please help.

## MENU.HTML (Here category listing for item populating)

```
<button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let cat of category_list" (click) = "openCategoryPage(cat)" menuClose>
       <ion-icon name="md-arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon> {{cat.name}}
</button>
```

## MENU.TS (Calling the item list page)

```
openCategoryPage(category) {
    this.childNavCtrl.setRoot('ItemsListPage',{'category': category});
 }
```

## ITEMLIST.TS

```
 export class ItemsListPage {

      @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
      woocommerce: any;
      products: any[];
      page: number;
      category: any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) 
     {
        this.page=1;
        this.category = this.navParams.get('category');
        this.products = [];

        this.woocommerce = WC({
          url:'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx',
          consumerKey:'ck_4c92xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          consumerSecret:'cs_ebd058cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          wpAPI: true,
          version: 'wc/v2',
          queryStringAuth: true
        });

          this.woocommerce.getAsync('products? 
         category='+this.category.id).then((data) =>{

             this.products = JSON.parse(data.body);

          },(err) =>{
             console.log(err);
          });
       }

       loadMoreItems(event){
         this.page++;
          this.woocommerce.getAsync('products? 
          category='+this.category.id+'&page='+this.page).then((data) =>{

            let temp = JSON.parse(data.body);

            this.products = this.products.concat(JSON.parse(data.body));
            event.complete();

            if(temp.length < 10){
               event.enable(false);
            }
           },(err) =>{
             console.log(err);
         });
       }
```

## ITEMLIST.HTML

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let product of products" text-wrap>
    <span *ngIf=product.price_html>
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img [src]= 'product.images[0].src' />
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <span [innerHTML]='product.name'></span>
      <ion-badge item-end><span [innerHTML]= "product.price_html"></span></ion-badge>
    </span>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMoreItems($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
    loadingSpinner="bubbles"
    loadingText="Loading more items...">
  </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

## Please check the following video about the exact issue that I have mentioned above

http://nimb.ws/isTAXE

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to add the NgZone**
Use the below code, It may be work.

```
 import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

  export class ItemsListPage {

  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  woocommerce: any;
  products: any[];
  page: number;
  category: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public zone: NgZone) 
 {
    this.page=1;
    this.category = this.navParams.get('category');
    this.products = [];

    this.woocommerce = WC({
      url:'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx',
      consumerKey:'ck_4c92xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      consumerSecret:'cs_ebd058cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      wpAPI: true,
      version: 'wc/v2',
      queryStringAuth: true
    });

      this.woocommerce.getAsync('products? 
     category='+this.category.id).then((data) =>{
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.products = JSON.parse(data.body);
        });
      },(err) =>{
         console.log(err);
      });
   }

   loadMoreItems(event){
     this.page++;
      this.woocommerce.getAsync('products? 
      category='+this.category.id+'&page='+this.page).then((data) =>{
        this.zone.run(() => {
            let temp = JSON.parse(data.body);

            this.products = this.products.concat(JSON.parse(data.body));
            event.complete();

            if(temp.length < 10){
            event.enable(false);
            }
        });
       },(err) =>{
         console.log(err);
     });
   }
```

Comment: This helped me too, though I do not understand why this behavior ?